# Which is the correct/better rule in .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-301

I want to remove a wiki section from my website which has been indexed by Google therefore I don't want to remove it and end up with loads of 404's when the pages are removed. I want to write a rule which will redirect all URL's requesting pages in the wiki to another single page.  So basically I want to redirect any URL containing the folder name /wiki/ to another page.  I'm a bit confused if this should be a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/* http://www.mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

or a RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /wiki/(.*) http://www.mydomain.com
```

Would appreciate some advice on which is correct/best and if this is the correct way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `RedirectMatch` in an `.htaccess` file, which solves the problem many times.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You are wrong -- it can be used there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Comment: @LazyOne: You are right. I wonder what I was confusing it with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both will do the same job. *But this idea is not good from SEO point of view* -- **for SEO will be better to return 410 code** (410 Gone -- page was here but no longer available).

In any case: `RedirectMatch` approach is recommended -- it uses slightly less CPU. On another hand, `RewriteRule` is more flexible.

For example: you have URL like `example.com/wiki/somepage?say=hello`. If you use `RedirectMatch` then new URL will be `example.com/?say=hello` -- as you can see query string was copied over. With RewriteRule you can easily and nicely drop it, so the new URL will be just `example.com/`.

Here are the rules (slightly optimized):

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wiki/.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/?
```

The `?` in both rules is for dropping existing query string. With RewriteRule it will not be there when redirect occurs (mod_rewrite is quite intelligent in this regard) while RedirectMatch is very straight forward and will keep it (which may look a bit odd if you are looking for really nice/proper URLs)